# "Adult and children stories" or "Adults and children stories"?

Tags: grammatical-number, compounds

How do you say it correctly?

- Adult and children stories
- Adults and children stories
- Adults' and children's stories
- other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean: if you said "adult stories" that would probably mean "porn". "Children's stories" would usually mean "stories by children" rather than "stories for children". The best fit for what you seem to mean is

> Stories for adults and children

or

> Stories for all ages

Comment: "Hundreds of stories for all ages to choose from" does it sounds good?

Comment: I disagree that "children's stories" would mean "stories by children." I work in book publishing, and "children's books" is the standard term for books written for children, typically by adults (with some exceptions.) I would use "stories" as a parallel to "books."

Comment: @In the: "I work in book publishing" weakens your argument: would that be understood the same way outside publishing?

Comment: @Master: Most definitely yes.

Answer (score 3):

I work in children's book publishing, and the standard within the industry would be children's stories, and would refer to stories written for children, usually written by adults.

In the kid's lit world we do use the term "adult books" to refer to non-porn books written for those over 18, but I admit that's not common usage outside this niche.

Answer (score 1):

Adults' and children's stories

That's probably what you mean.

Comment: And he's wide open, running for the end zone, but OH NO HE TRIPS AT THE FIVE YARD LINE! :P

Comment: @mmyers - didnt get the joke.

Comment: Check the edit history.